# How can I move a banner ad outside the 960px width

Tags: css, wordpress, banner

I have a [news site](http://www.vincenttimes.com/living/healthy-living/2012/12/08/12373/e-cigarettes-are-they-harmful-to-our-health/) and have a 300x600 banner in the middle of every post on the left side.

I want to move the banner 150px outside the 960px wide "page", so the banner is half in and half out.The only way I have figured out how to move the banner left is `position:absolute`, but the text doesnt wrap around the banner - which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `position:absolute` doesn't wrap text because you are removing the element from the flow of the [document](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning).

You can margin it out by 150px using `margin-left:-150px` however, your css for the class `.entry` has `overflow:hidden` which will have to be removed in order for you to margin the banner ad outside the 960px post. Just be careful that removing that property doesn't cause other problems with your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the property `margin-left:-150px;`